# Overlapping image on Jobs

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, stack-overflow-jobs, images

[Jobs has a page where the image overlaps the text](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/cv/set-search-state?ref=a):

[image: Error in the page]

Here is the version of Chrome I am using:

[image: Chrome version]

In text, that is:

> Version 54.0.2815.0 canary (64-bit).

I've also signed up for Jobs.

Comment: That link leads to a 404 for me. (It might have something to do with account settings, can anyone else see it?)

Comment: @Laurel, is Jobs enabled for you?

Comment: @Laurel yep I can see it https://i.imgur.com/HknmRlL.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This "page" is typically rendered inside a popup when a user clicks on the *Update Status* button on https://stackoverflow.com/jobs:

[image]

=>

[image]

We've just added a small styling fix to make sure it also renders correctly as a full page in case a user hits https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/cv/set-search-state directly.